# Newbie need help on a django view element

Tags: django

In my django tutorial I see alot of "context_dict" in the views file.
I can't really find a clear answer on where it is actually used.

Hopefully one of you can explain this ^^

Answer (score 1):

It's referring to the `RequestContext` that is passed to the template. A lot of tutorials construct the request context in a very outdated way. Django's `render` shortcut function will take care of constructing the context instance for you:

```
from django.shortcuts import render

def your_view(request):
    context = {'foo': 'bar'}
    return render(request, 'some-template.html', context)
```

In this case, the positional argument `context` gets passed in as argument to the `RequestContext` class behind the scenes.

Comment: You're welcome. There are still edge cases when you need to construct a `RequestContext` by hand, so it's good to know both ways.